# how to upload a .txt file and save to another directory using a html,php,css and javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I want to upload .txt file using "Choose File" button and then those uploaded .txt files will be saved into another directory. After clicking "Save" button. Scenario.

`folder/source/tbl_household.txt,tbl_member.txt`

will be copied to:

`folder/target/tbl.household.txt,tbl_member.txt`

What should I do ? I am new in php, html, css, javascript.
Here is my code....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Mini Ajax File Upload Form</title>

    <!-- Google web fonts -->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:400,700" rel='stylesheet' />

    <!-- The main CSS file -->
    <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>

    <form id="upload" method="post" action="upload.php"      enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div id="drop">
            Drop Here

            <a>Choose File</a>

            <input type="file"  name="upl" multiple />
        </div>

        <ul>
            <!-- The file uploads will be shown here -->
        </ul>

    <footer>
        <h2><a href="http://tutorialzine.com/2013/05/mini-ajax-file-upload-  form/"><i>Tutorial:</i> Mini Ajax File Upload Form</a></h2>
        <div id="tzine-actions">

            <a id="tzine-download"  href="http://tutorialzine.com/2013/05/mini-ajax-file-upload-form/"  title="Download This Example!">Download</a>

        </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- JavaScript Includes -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.knob.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/textfile.js"></script>


    <!-- jQuery File Upload Dependencies -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script> 
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script> 
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script> 

    <!-- Our main JS file -->
    <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script> 


    <!-- Only used for the demos. Please ignore and remove. --> 
    <script src="http://cdn.tutorialzine.com/misc/enhance/v1.js" async> </script>
    <button type="button" id="drop1" align ="center" action="save.php"  >SAVE</button>

</body>
</html>
```

And my upload.php part

```
<?php

// A list of permitted file extensions
$allowed = array('png', 'jpg', 'gif','zip');

if(isset($_FILES['upl']) && $_FILES['upl']['error'] == 0){

    $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['upl']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if(!in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowed)){
        echo '{"status":"error"}';
        exit;
    }

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.$_FILES['upl'] ['name'])){
        echo '{"status":"success"}';
        exit;
    }
}

echo '{"status":"error"}';
exit;
```

Sorry. Here is my script.js

```
$(function(){
var ul = $('#upload ul');
$('#drop a').click(function(){
// Simulate a click on the file input button
// to show the file browser dialog
$(this).parent().find('input').click();
});
// Initialize the jQuery File Upload plugin
$('#upload').fileupload({
// This element will accept file drag/drop uploading
dropZone: $('#drop'),
// This function is called when a file is added to the queue;
// either via the browse button, or via drag/drop:
add: function (e, data) {
var tpl = $('<li class="working"><input type="text" value="0" data-   width="48" data-height="48"'+
' data-fgColor="#0788a5" data-readOnly="1" data-bgColor="#3e4043" /><p></p>  <span></span></li>');
// Append the file name and file size
tpl.find('p').text(data.files[0].name).append('<i>' +  formatFileSize(data.files[0].size) + '</i>');

        // Add the HTML to the UL element
        data.context = tpl.appendTo(ul);

        // Initialize the knob plugin
        tpl.find('input').knob();

        // Listen for clicks on the cancel icon
        tpl.find('span').click(function(){

            if(tpl.hasClass('working')){
                jqXHR.abort();
            }

            tpl.fadeOut(function(){
                tpl.remove();
            });

        });

        // Automatically upload the file once it is added to the queue
        var jqXHR = data.submit();
    },

    progress: function(e, data){

        // Calculate the completion percentage of the upload
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);

        // Update the hidden input field and trigger a change
        // so that the jQuery knob plugin knows to update the dial
        data.context.find('input').val(progress).change();

        if(progress == 100){
            data.context.removeClass('working');
        }
    },

    fail:function(e, data){
        // Something has gone wrong!
        data.context.addClass('error');
    }

});


// Prevent the default action when a file is dropped on the window
$(document).on('drop dragover', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});

// Helper function that formats the file sizes
function formatFileSize(bytes) {
    if (typeof bytes !== 'number') {
        return '';
    }

    if (bytes >= 1000000000) {
        return (bytes / 1000000000).toFixed(2) + ' GB';
    }

    if (bytes >= 1000000) {
        return (bytes / 1000000).toFixed(2) + ' MB';
    }

    return (bytes / 1000).toFixed(2) + ' KB';
}

});
```

Comment: Where is the content of script.js?

Comment: @satyrwilder. Sorry sir. I've added my .js :)

Comment: @satyrwilder ? i've added the script.js file.

Answer (score 1):

Add `'txt'` extension:

```
$allowed = array('png', 'jpg', 'gif','zip','txt');
```

and remove the button:

```
<button type="button"  align ="center"  name="save" value="save"  >SAVE</button>
```

and add this line:

```
<input type="submit" value="save" />
```